# How can I add a Chrome extension listener both onStartup and onInstalled?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The [chrome.runtime API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) has a few events that I can use to add a listener to a context menu. At the moment I'm using `chrome.runtime.onStartup` like so:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title': 'Add: %s',
    'contexts': ['selection']
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);
```

The problem is that `chrome.runtime.onStartup` will work when the user starts or restarts Chrome, and `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` will work when the extension or Chrome is first installed or updated.

If I only do `onStartup`, then my context menu won't be there when my extension or Chrome is next updated. If I only do `onInstalled`, then my context menu won't persist after the user restarts Chrome.

How can I handle both cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually an interesting question, since the behavior differs depending on whether you're using an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) or a [persistent background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

**Note that this answer is specific to `contextMenu` API!**

### Persistent background page

You should simply put your code on the top level.

Then it will execute every time your extension's background page is loaded.

If you have a persistent background page, that's exactly what you want: execute once when the extension starts *for whatever reason*.

If you want to make sure you don't create a duplicate item, include an `id` attribute in `create()`.

Google has a [corresponding sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic/sample.js).

### Event page

Event page is loaded much more often than a regular one throughout the lifetime of an extension. And anyway, context menu API requires *special treatment* with event pages.

First off, including an `id` attribute in `contextMenus.create()` is a *requirement* for event pages. Also, because code is unloaded when idle, you have to use `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` instead of an `onclick` attribute.

Documentation recommends using `onInstalled`:

> If you need to do some initialization when your extension is installed or upgraded, listen to the `runtime.onInstalled` event. This is a good place to register for `declarativeWebRequest` rules, **`contextMenu` entries**, and other such one-time initialization.

Indeed, that's what they do in [the sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/event_page/sample.js).

I tested it, and indeed the context menus persist through restart of the extension and the browser. This difference is not explicitly documented, though.

**Bug Alert!** In view of Rob W's comment about [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388231), the method is not 100% reliable if the extension happens to be disabled.

Comment: In theory, registering context menu items in onInstalled should work. In practice, this does not always happen: When the extension is disabled while the extension is updated, the old context menus are removed, but the new ones are not installed because onInstalled is not called while the extension is disabled (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388231).

Comment: @RobW That is.. Sad. Rare case, but still important. And the bug is untouched for almost a year.

Comment: @RobW _In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, however.._