# contextmenu disappears sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    if (!info.srcUrl)
        return;
    console.log(info.srcUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url : "https://hizliresim.com/p/eklenti-yukle",
        headers : {
            Accept : "application/json"
        },
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            remote_file_url : info.srcUrl
        },
        success : function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < data.images.length; imageIndex++) {
                var resultImage = data.images[imageIndex];
                if (resultImage.status == 0) {
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    document.body.appendChild(input);
                    input.value = resultImage.image_url.replace('hizli', 'i.hizli') + ".jpg";
                    input.select();
                    document.execCommand('copy', false, null);
                    input.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id : "menu_upload_image",
        title : "Hızlı Resim'e Yükle",
        contexts : ["image"]
    });
});
```

Here is the `background.js`. It works when I reload the extension, but after a while the context menu at the images disappears.

I think `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` may be not enough.

What may be the problem?

edit: here is the manifest.json

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "jquery.js","background.js" ]
   },
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "go.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "description": "test",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon.jpg",
      "16": "icon.jpg",
      "48": "icon.jpg"
   },   
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "testaddon",
   "permissions": [ "contextMenus","bookmarks", "unlimitedStorage", "notifications", "clipboardWrite", "notifications", "clipboardRead", "management", "tabs", "history", "cookies", "idle", "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "contentSettings", "*://*/*" ],
   "version": "14.53"
}
```

Comment: What's the `background` key from your manifest?

Comment: I don't actually see a problem with your code. Here's [my previous answer on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30014338/934239), but you seem to be doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
(When the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) is persistent, which is default)
You create the context menu when the extension is installed. That's why it  shows only after installation, until the browser is closed.
You should simply create the context menu button when extension starts (remove it from onInstalled listener):

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
  //....
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id : "menu_upload_image",
  title : "Hızlı Resim'e Yükle",
  contexts : ["image"]
});
```

**Option 2**
(When using an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages))
When the background page is not persistent, you should add this to your manifest (`"persistent": false`):

```
{
  ....
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,

  },
  ....
}
```

In this case, you can keep the context menu creation in `onInstalled` event handler.

See the first 2 examples from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contextmenus), where the difference between 2 approaches is visible.

Comment: Thing is, normally Chrome remembers that for context menus. It may be a bug. Then again, gotta see the `background` key to know if it's a persistent background page.

Comment: I think OP uses event page approach of menu's creation. :)

Comment: Yes, I see it would be a problem if he used the event page approach for a persistent page.

Comment: it solved but however nearly every sample code related with contextmenu on google includes "onInstalled.addListener" thing

Comment: @MustafaMarsliTopaloğlu onInstalled is used because the event page is a recommended approach: it saves memory resources.