# When to perform certain actions in a Google Extension: onStartup, onInstalled, or just in the JS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Not usually a fan of asking these kind of open ended questions but I cant find any reliable documentation (either independent or from google) that is very clear and tutorials and examples all conflict with each other.

Currently I'm working with `chrome.commands.onCommand` as well as `chrome.tabs.onCreated` and `chrome.tabs.onActivated` but I'm interested in general guidelines as well (which it seems to me may be impossible).  I've found a few resources such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014062/how-can-i-add-a-chrome-extension-listener-both-onstartup-and-oninstalled) and [the samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) but the samples are mostly one liners (WHY) and the only useful SO link I found specifically states that the post is specific to that API.

I'm using a persistent background page (since the SO answer says that matters) and really like the quote included from the documentation:

> If you need to do some initialization when your extension is installed or upgraded, listen to the runtime.onInstalled event. This is a good place to register for declarativeWebRequest rules, contextMenu entries, and other such one-time initialization

But I'm currently doing all my registration in `runtime.onInstalled` and lose keybinds (tab stuff still seems to work but relies on the keybinds so I can't tell for sure) when the browser crashes and restarts.  I'd think keybinds are a one-time initialization thing but clearly not. I could just move the keybinds to onStartup as I know it doesn't work in onInstalled but I'd prefer to know best practices for extensions (who cares if I don't use the best practice for some random library, but extensions are all about the best code imo).

Any help would be appreciated, and if any other info is needed feel free to leave a comment and let me know.  I'd prefer to not have to come up with a minimum example though if possible though and keep this to guidelines for `chrome.commands`, `chrome.tabs`, as well as general guidelines for persistent pages (although event pages would be appreciated since there seem to be no good resources and others may find this question in the future).

Comment: There's no need for a persistent background script here (AFAICT without seeing the actual code). Use an event page so that all your listeners are registered each time the page is resumed (e.g. at the start of the script). There are just a few exceptions that should be registered only once (after an upgrade etc) inside runtime.onInstalled such as contextMenus, declarativeXXXX.

Comment: Also, no need to complicate things when you use a persistent background script - there's usually no need for onStartup at all since the script runs just once anyway so you can simply put the code at the start of script (so it'll run after the extension has crashed and was restarted too).

Comment: In addition to what @wOxxOm has already said - you probably don't want to use `onInstalled` here, since that will only fire when the extension is installed or updated. So if the user closes their browser and then reopens it, your listeners will not be added (unless there happens to be an update available for your extension at the time). Also, on the off-chance that you want this extension to be cross-browser, note that event pages currently have poor support in other browsers, so a persistent background page would be easier.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate the help both of you (can only tag one person per message so I'll tag no one).  I definitely could use an event page however keeping it persistent just seemed like the right idea in the long run (doesn't seem to be any huge side effects and my extension is light weight).  Given what err has said I'll continue with the background page and take both of your advice and simply register everything outside of `onInstalled` and `onStartup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the useful info by @wOxxOm and @err1100 I've decided to self answer this question.  I like using comments in the question for clarification, however I often see SO users answering the question in the comments instead of posting an answer (maybe because the answers in the comments are usually more conversational than stating an answer) but either way I think questions deserve answers.  If either of them posts an answer I'll accept the first to post or if someone other than them posts a significantly better answer (don't go stealing their credit).

## Persistent Pages:

Persistent pages apparently have better support across different browsers and so should be preferred in that case (at least as of 11/24/2018).  Otherwise consider using an event page if the extension is just for Chrome as persistence is rarely needed.

#### onInstalled:

Context menus and anything with the `declarativeXXXX` naming scheme should be initialized once in the `onInstalled` event but there aren't many other things requiring one time initialization.

#### onStartup:

With persistent pages the script is loaded once and never unloaded unless the browser is closed and so `onStartup` doesn't have much of a use.

#### In the Script:

As said above, since the script is loaded only once per browser restart (and also ran once if installed on an already running browser) all per browsing session initalization can be done here.

## Event Pages:

I didn't have a clear idea of exactly what the use of non persistent pages were (I believe this is what wOxxOm is referring to as an event page as googling it takes me to defunct documentation and redirects to documentation without the term) prior to this question so I'll clear that up for those who may be in the same boat.  A non persistent script is ran (at some point, IDK and won't be testing this) and registers it's event listeners.  After that the script dies but the listeners remain meaning that initialization can be done with `onInstalled` and `onStartup` (since I know for sure when these are run and not when the non persistent page script is ran) and all the events you registered to listen for will reactivate that part of your script (really just runs the callback provided but whatever).

#### onInstalled:

Just like with Persistent pages use this for the same things that require one time initialization.

#### onStartup:

I'd leave no code in the script and everything in a listener if creating an event page but I'm not well versed in event pages so I'll update this if someone comments on it being wrong.  Stuff requiring initialization each browser restart would be in this listener.

#### In the Script:

As said above, I don't have a great understanding of event scripts but it seems like the only code in your script should be for setting up listeners and whatever variables those listeners need.  No significant scripting should occur in the script however do as you must to make your extension of course (or just use a persistent page).